# How to open files with unknown extension

Tags: 18.04

I have file with extension ".application" which I want to open, but I don't know how.. :/
I do have PlayOnLinux if it can help me in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find anything specific about how to launch these Microsoft 'ClickOnce' files with PlayOnLinux. However, there is [a Wine FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_install.2Frun_a_ClickOnce_.28.application.29_file.3F) on it which suggests:

```
wine start whatever.application
```

PlayOnLinux uses wine so you should already have it installed. You may also need to use [winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks) to install the version of .NET required by the application.

## Winetricks Installation

```
cd "${HOME}/Downloads"
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks
```

## Installing .NET (4.0) with winetricks example

```
bash winetricks dotnet40
```

## Edit: Finding out about unknown extensions

If in future you have a file with an unknown extension (or no extension at all) the [file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/file.1.html) command can tell you about the file:

```
file a-jpeg-file-with-wrong-ext.txt
```

Outputs:

```
a-jpeg-file-with-wrong-ext.txt: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01 etc
```

Additionally, you can look up extensions online. A good database for this is [fileinfo.com](https://fileinfo.com/extension/application).